# How to have "find ... -exec ..." return execution errors?

Tags: find, gnu

I would like to traverse a directory tree with GNU `find` and execute a command via `-exec` option.

I would like to have `find` failing with non-zero return code as soon as the executed program returns non-zero value.

I have been reading the [friendly manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) but could not find any way of doing so.

I am aware I could be trying to achieve something actually un-achievable!